# django+uwsgi logging with TimedRotatingFileHandler "overwrites rotated log file"

Tags: python, django, logging, nginx, uwsgi

I recently switched my django production web app from `apache+mod_wsgi` to `nginx+uwsgi` in `emperor mode`. All it's ok except Time Rotated log files.
My web app uses a log file named **appname.log** to log all requests, and with apache it *rotates at midnight* without problems.

With `uwsgi` the file rotates at midnight but some uwsgi process/worker writes into this rotated file (example rotated file: *appname.log.2017-01-08*) instead of write into **appname.log** , **this cause that the rotated file is overwritten**.

A solution seems to be **touching the uwsgi .ini file** (I'm not completely sure...), but I don't want to restart/reload uwsgi if a user is still connected to my app.

There is a possibility or a configuration that I can use to notify to all uwsgi process that the logfile is changed without restarting the web app?
If possible I would have the same behaviour that I have in `apache+mod_wsgi`.

[ConcurrentLogHandler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ConcurrentLogHandler/0.9.1), is too old and I don't want use syslog or logrotate :)

Someone have same problems? someone have suggestions?

thanx

This is my setting:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s];[%(levelname)s];[Proc:%(process)d];[Thread:%(thread)d];%(module)s-%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d;Msg:%(message)s;'
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': LOG_FILE,
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
            'backupCount': 365,
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'null': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.NullHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false']
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        APP_NAME: {
            'handlers': ['console', 'file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'INFO',
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
```

Comment: At the moment, seems there is not solution using only django for rotating log files. With great disappoint.
My "workaround" solution, waiting to have a better django/uwsgi solution, is a simple `logrotate` configuration with `copytruncate` option.
Into django I use `logging.FileHandler` to handle my log file. Now django doesn't manage at all the log rotation, but is logrotate (with `cron`) that manages the log rotation.


I Wait for a real better solution, that not use softwares other than django and uwsgi.

Answer (score 2):

We have experienced the same problem with nginx+gunicorn. We had very similar settings:

```
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "verbose": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s"},
        "simple": {"format": "%(levelname)s %(asctime)s  %(message)s", "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"},
    },
    "filters": {
          "require_debug_true": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue"},
          "require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"},
    },
    "handlers": {
        "logfile": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
            "when": "D",
            "interval": 10, 
            "backupCount": 100,
            "filename": LOG_FILE,
            "formatter": "simple",
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {    
        APP_NAME: {
            "handlers": ["console", "plus_logfile"],
            "propagate": True,
            "level": "DEBUG",
        },
    },
}
```

According to [Python Logging Cookbook](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) - [Logging to a single file from multiple processes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes):

*Although logging is thread-safe, and logging to a single file from multiple threads in a single process is supported, logging to a single file from multiple processes is not supported, because there is no standard way to serialize access to a single file across multiple processes in Python. If you need to log to a single file from multiple processes, one way of doing this is to have all the processes log to a SocketHandler, and have a separate process which implements a socket server which reads from the socket and logs to file. (If you prefer, you can dedicate one thread in one of the existing processes to perform this function.)*

So the best way is to have a socket listener that listens multiple uwsgi workers and logs simultaneously.

Setting would look like this:

```
"loggers": {    
    APP_NAME: {
        "handlers": ["console", "plus_logfile"],
        "propagate": True,
        "level": "DEBUG",
    },
},
```

And you can find an example listener code [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#network-logging). This code however writes to console. So if you want to write to file you need to edit the listener script.

Answer (score 0):

Completely aligned with [cgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1257959/cgl) solution but if you don't want to build a socket listener and want a production-level solution without missing the logs then you can do the below steps which I did in my current org.

1. Linux/Unix logrotate with create option
2. Along with logrotate you need to use [Watchedfilehandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#watchedfilehandler). It watches the file stream on every emit and if the file name changes it closes it and reopens it with the filename.

You don't need to reload/restart your Django application and you will not miss logs also. We haven't found any issues with this approach till now.